# Retrieve a word from file name in python

Tags: python, string, pandas, filenames, series

I have list of 5 excel files in a specific path as mentioned below : `'Z:\\Ruchika\\Citymax_Dec06\\SVCDs\\**\\*Claypot*.csv'.` 
The list of 5 excel files and the paths are as per below

```
['Z:\\Ruchika\\Citymax_Dec06\\SVCDs\\December - SVCD\\UAE _ Citymax _Claypot_ Burdubai_fullcampaignfile.csv',
 'Z:\\Ruchika\\Citymax_Dec06\\SVCDs\\January2019 - SVCD\\UAE _ Citymax _Claypot_ Burdubai_fullcampaignfile.csv',
 'Z:\\Ruchika\\Citymax_Dec06\\SVCDs\\November - SVCD\\UAE _ Citymax _ Claypot_BD_fullcampaignfile.csv',
 'Z:\\Ruchika\\Citymax_Dec06\\SVCDs\\October - SVCD\\UAE _ Citymax _Claypot_ Burdubai_fullcampaignfile.csv',
 'Z:\\Ruchika\\Citymax_Dec06\\SVCDs\\sept - svcd\\UAE _ Claypot _ Burdubai_fullcampaignfile.csv']
```

Now I am trying to retrieve the Month name from each excel file name and add to my data frames as per below code, but getting struck as I am able to retrieve only for November Month which is incorrect. Please help me

```
m=['November','December','October','September','August']
    def extract(folderpath):
        final=glob.glob(folderpath)
        frames = []
        for file in final:
            j=0
            df = pd.read_csv(file, error_bad_lines=False)
            df['Month']=m[j]
            frames.append(df)
            j=j+1
        mergedfile = pd.concat(frames)
        return mergedfile

a=extract('Z:\\Ruchika\\Citymax_Dec06\\SVCDs\\**\\*Claypot*.csv')

Input : a.shape
Ouput : (3232487, 31)

Input : a['Month'].value_counts()
Output : November   3232487
         Name: Month, dtype: int64
```

Comment: What have you tried? Where are you stuck? Or are you expecting people to do your work for you?

Comment: So you want to add a column that is just the word "December" every time?

Comment: @JoshFriedlander I wanted to add a column "Month" in which it contains only the word "December" every row in the data frame

Comment: @LieRyan I have tried using for loop and if statement, but got stuck in the middle

Comment: You have it in your code, `df['Month']='December'`. What are you getting stuck on?

Comment: @JoshFriedlander I am getting stuck on retrieving the word "December" from the file name and assign it to the column "Month" in df

Comment: @JoshFriedlander I have shown the code only for reference which I need to achieve

Comment: so your question is how to extract the string `December` from the string `Z:\Ruchika\Citymax_Dec06\SVCDs\December - SVCD\UAE _ Citymax Claypot Burdubai_fullcampaignfile.csv` with a regex?

Comment: @JoshFriedlander yes

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing it can be any month, so why not just check for months:

```
filename = r'Z:\Ruchika\Citymax_Dec06\SVCDs\December - SVCD\UAE _ Citymax Claypot Burdubai_fullcampaignfile.csv'

for month in ['October', 'November', 'December']: # List of months
    if month in filename:
        print('Month is:', month)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
month = [x for x in month_list if x in my_filename][0]
my_df['month'] = month
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`str.split`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) with [`pd.DataFrame.assign`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.assign.html):

```
file_path = r'Z:\Ruchika\Citymax_Dec06\SVCDs\December - SVCD\UAE _ Citymax Claypot Burdubai_fullcampaignfile.csv'

file_month = file_path.rsplit('\\', 2)[1].split(' - ')[0]  # December
df = pd.read_csv(file_path).assign(Month=file_month)
```